# Detect Dir after / in a URL

Tags: php, url

I want to write a PHP script which will first detect URL's and see if they have sub dir or not, if they are simple URL like site.com then it would write 1 in one of the DB's table but if the URL is something like this site.com/images or site.com/images/files then it should'nt do the query..

EDIT: Answer by Mob it works but doesnt work if there are more than one url

```
 $url = "http://lol.com";
 $v = parse_url($url);

 if (isset( $v['path']) && (!empty($v['path'])) && ($v['path'] != "/") ){
 echo "yeah";
 } else { 
 echo "nah";
 }
```

Comment: Removed 'SQL' tag. This question has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: ok i though i mentioned about database and all so had added it

Comment: It worked Thanks ! :)) May you live a long life! :)

Comment: I will pray for you each time now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$url = "http://lol.com";
$v = parse_url($url);

if (isset( $v['path']) && (!empty($v['path'])) && ($v['path'] != "/") ){
       echo "yeah";
   } else { 
       echo "nah";
   }
```

***EDIT:***

To parse multiple urls;

- Store the urls in an array.
- Use a loop to iterate over the array while passing the values to a function that performs the check

Here:

```
<?php


$arr = array("http://google.com",
             "http://google.com/image/",
             "http://flickr.com",
             "http://flickr.com/image" );

foreach ($arr as $val){
    echo $val."       ". check($val)."\n";
}

function check ($url){
$v = parse_url($url);

if (isset( $v['path']) && (!empty($v['path'])) && ($v['path'] != "/") ){
           return "true";
       } else { 
           return "false";
       }
}
    ?>
```

The output is :

```
http://google.com              false
http://google.com/image/       true
http://flickr.com              false
http://flickr.com/image        true
```

Comment: now suppose i add many sites to detect their URL , in that case it doesnt work, how to do that??

Comment: Thanks Brother :) but the URL is a single variable known as $site  and there is no expected lengh of URLS as they are submitted by users so .. how ?? you have helped me this far hope u can help me more :)

Comment: The `URL` is a single variable? Then just use `$_POST['url']` as the `path`. . . I don't understand you well.

Comment: i mean when user submits like 30 Domains they are submitted in a form textarea known as Text and then in each line is a domain so i want each one of them to be seen by the script not just one site now u get it brother??

Comment: Edit: I added it inside the loop and it worked Thanks!! Love u brother!! ^_^
Edit: Not working perfectly with many sites :(

Comment: Edit: I added a where clause in SQL query and its working like anything Thanks a lot for the help brother may you live long life :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Syntax: `strpos($haystack, $needle)`

You could use something like:

```
if (!strpos($url, '/'))
{
    do_query();
}
```

*edit*
Remember to strip the slashes in http://, of course.

Comment: well, that will probably work for the strings in this question, but I'd be hesitant to use this as a general function: `http://` would be caught, as would the third slash in `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER is what you need. I'll let you google it.